# Fastest method of finding data from another row in Pandas DataFrame based upon column data calculation?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mapping

Without resorting to looping thru each individual row of the dataframe, which can be very slow for large datasets, how do I used the calculated result of two columns in a row, `2*A - B`, to find a value in column `B` and from that new row pull data from column `C`  and place into column `D` of the original row.

In the DataFrame below for example, row `2` has `2*A - B` equal `1`.  Column `B` in row `0` has a `1`, so data from column `C` in row `0` should be placed in column `D` of row `2`.

```
In [1] import pandas as pd
In [2] a = [3,3,3]
In [3] b = [1,3,5]
In [4] c = [3,4,5]

In [5] df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': a , 'B': b, 'C':c})
Out[5] print(df1)

   A  B  C
0  3  1  3
1  3  3  4
2  3  5  5
```

The resulting DataFrame should look like this:

```
    A  B  C  D
0   3  1  3  5
1   3  3  4  4
2   3  5  5  3
```

I'm assuming that there is only one unique value for each combination of `A` and `B`.  While the example above could be accomplished by a simply transposing column `C` into column `D`, I would like a more generic solution that is extendable to situations where the data is not amenable to transposing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pd.DataFrame.eval`

```
df1.assign(D=df1.eval('2 * A - B').map(df1.set_index('B').C))

   A  B  C  D
0  3  1  3  5
1  3  3  4  4
2  3  5  5  3
```

---

But if fast is what you want.

```
m = dict(zip(df1.B.values.tolist(), df1.C.values.tolist()))
a = df1.A.values
b = df1.B.values
z = 2 * a - b

df1.assign(D=[m[i] for i in z.tolist()])

   A  B  C  D
0  3  1  3  5
1  3  3  4  4
2  3  5  5  3
```

Comment: You're right, the second method is 2-3 times faster than first method, which is itself significantly faster than the other solution.  Due to this, I'm marking your answer as the solution.  Although the other solution had a better explanation of their method.

Answer (score 3):

If you can guarantee unique combinations, then...

```
mapping = dict(df[['B', 'C']].values)
df['D'] = (2 * df.A - df.B).replace(mapping)
df    
   A  B  C  D
0  3  1  3  5
1  3  3  4  4
2  3  5  5  3
```

Create a mapping of `B` values to `C` values. Perform the operation (2 * A - B), and use the `mapping` generated earlier to get the appropriate `C` value.

If a mapping does not exist, the computed value is not replaced. If you would like it to be replaced with `NaN`, you might use `map` instead:

```
df['D'] = (2 * df.A - df.B).map(mapping)
df
   A  B  C  D
0  3  1  3  5
1  3  3  4  4
2  3  5  5  3
```

It works as `df.replace` would, but non-mapped values are replaced with `NaN`.